# Old printer text format c#

Tags: c#, printing, formatting, plaintext

I have the following output generated by an UNIX machine from 1996... We are upgrading the software for Windows, and I need to create this exact output http://pastebin.com/YBHpSYDW from C#

There are some problems I can't handle, because I don't know how...

How can I determinate the columns, set aligment for the "IMPORTE" column to the right, if it is plaintext?

I have done this output in Excel which is more readable, flexible.. but they want this creepy old stuff *because a lot of reasons* and they I'll become insane working for this people, they don't want to upgrade anything, just the software but keep every old creepy thing @ output...

So if anyone knows a way to do this, it'll be so much helpful, thank you.

**EDIT**
The output is a list of data from an SQL Server, old data was stored into MultiValue .DAT and .IDX files, but now they're in a SQL Server... So basically, the code that generates the values is the following

```
var Query = getRows(sel.DataTable).Select(row =>
{
    return new
    {
        banco = row["banco"].ToString(),
        emisora = row["emisora"].ToString(),
        sucursal = row["sucursal"].ToString(),
        fecha = row["fecha"].ToString(),
        identificacion = row["identificacion"].ToString(),
        importe = row["importe"].ToString(),
        importe_dec = row["importe_dec"].ToString(),
        provincia = row["provincia"].ToString(),
        referencia = row["referencia"].ToString(),
    };
});
```

Then I do some foreach to make the magic... For example

```
foreach (var banco in Query.GroupBy(l => l.banco))
```

So the problem is the output file for printing...

**EDIT 2**
Got it working, here's the code

```
private void generarFicheroPrt()
{
    try
    {
        SelectBD sel = new SelectBD(Program.ConexBD, "SELECT * FROM Seguros");
        var Query = getRows(sel.DataTable).Select(row =>
        {
            return new
            {
                banco = row["banco"].ToString(),
                emisora = row["emisora"].ToString(),
                sucursal = row["sucursal"].ToString(),
                fecha = row["fecha"].ToString(),
                identificacion = row["identificacion"].ToString(),
                importe = row["importe"].ToString(),
                importe_dec = row["importe_dec"].ToString(),
                provincia = row["provincia"].ToString(),
                referencia = row["referencia"].ToString(),
            };
        });
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Program.path + @"\CV9005.prt"))
        {
            int i = 1;
            int pag = 0;
            int linea = 1;
            sw.WriteLine();
            sw.WriteLine("\x1b&l1O\x1b(s14H");
            decimal total = 0;
            foreach (var valor in Query.OrderBy(l => l.emisora))
            {
                if (linea == 48) linea = 1;
                if (linea == 1)
                {
                    pag++;
                    sw.WriteLine("\xc\t0125 BANCOFAR" + string.Empty.PadLeft(37, '\x20') + "COBRO POR VENTANILLA S. S. - CONTROL DE DOCUMENTOS     PAG.     "+ pag  +"\n\n");
                    sw.WriteLine("\t N.ORDEN  NUMERO REFERENCIA           IMPORTE  SUC.  EMISORA");
                    sw.WriteLine("\t -------  -----------------  ----------------  ----  -----------------------------------------------------------");
                    sw.WriteLine();
                }
                setSufijoEmisora(valor.emisora);
                decimal importe = Convert.ToDecimal(Int32.Parse(valor.importe) + "," + valor.importe_dec);
                string imp = importe.ToString("N2", Cultures.Spain);
                sw.WriteLine("\t\t" + string.Format("{0, 4}\t{1, -13}\t\t{2, 13}{3,6}  {4, -59}", i.ToString(), valor.referencia, imp, valor.sucursal, valor.emisora + " " + sufijoEmisora));
                i++;
                linea++;
                total = total + importe;
            }
            sw.WriteLine();
            sw.WriteLine("\t\t\t\t\t TOTAL .....\t" + string.Format("{0, 13}", total.ToString("N2", Cultures.Spain)));
        };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.log(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can u please elaborate a bit more like how are you generating the output? Are you using tables to generate this output? Relevant code snippet will be very helpful to give any suggestion.

Comment: updated with the code that generates the output..

Comment: Where are you outputting this to, on a console?, to a text file? directly to a printer? If you are outputting to a text file then you can use the "PrintDocument" tool from the tool box and format the document as you like; or if you want to create a word document then use the "Microsoft.Office.Core" library. This library has a document property in whice you edit a lot of things like you do in word.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.aspx

Comment: I am outputting this to a plain text file, which must be *.PRT extension because UNIX used that... I can't use Word because of the ASCII characters that I must insert on the output file like `SOH`, `FF`, `ESC` etc...

Comment: oldstyle, quick and dirty: use foreach, WriteLine, String.Format and \t (for tab) ,Environment.Newline,... and so on ... oh, and make sure if you wan't an unix or windows format (Environment.Newline will give the one from the OS, is they parse with some unix tool and you create on windows there can be problems). See http://www.csharp-examples.net/align-string-with-spaces/

Comment: This method will work if you hard code the string, but for a file like the one the OP posted, would require a generic formatting. One of the way this can be achieved through using the MS office core dll.

Comment: I haven't used MS Office Core neither Environment.Newline :( so I'm lost but your comments are helpful.

Comment: @jegan : you only need to hard code the format. For the rest you put variables in. Its a thing used a long time ago...  With the Office.Core he will format an existing document, not putting data to a text file (the document seems to have fixed line numbers, therefore everything can get computed quite easy - all that is needed are plain text files - Office.Core are Office interops which computes with fonts etc.pp. - if it is further processed by some old style unix program you can have problems...) (this is not only about unicode, also about line endings etc.pp.)

Comment: I'm getting it :) the problem I have now, is how I set every 52 lines the header again? I mean, I can make a foreach but I need it to stop if there are no more results in query... =/

Comment: you probably need two foreach loop, foreach header do  foreach content do line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "PrintDocument" tool from the toolbox.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

This will help you with basic formating.

**Edit**

For more richer formating and saving to file use the Microsoft.Office.Core namespace,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.aspx

If you want non ASCII encoding, make sure to set the encoding as per your requirement and save the file with the required encoding.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.msoencoding.aspx

```
using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("a.txt", false, Encoding.UTF8))
{
   writer.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Comment: This actually will send to the printer, I need to create a plain text file, so we can print it and also send via email for example, or just save on our PC...

Comment: See my edit on links to document properties and saving files in unicode.